# What undergraduate math course would cover metric spaces?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, vector-spaces, metric-spaces

I'm looking for an undergraduate course in mathematics that would be likely to cover [material like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)). I suspect maybe this approach to math is called Metric Spaces, but I'm not sure.

It seems to come up a lot in computer science and I'd like to explore the subject more rigorously.

Comment: Elementary topology.

Comment: Real analysis might or might not.

Comment: Depends on the country. In Germany these are covered in the first semester introductionary course to analysis.

Comment: In the US it's also generally called "Elementary Real Analysis" although you might also find it in "Advanced Calculus".

Comment: And I would suggest that a topology course, even if it (eventually) includes metric spaces, is *not* the right place for a computer scientist to try to get their metric fix.

Comment: @dbx - What would be the right place for a computer scientist to get their metric fix in the US? Real Analysis?

Comment: Yes, beginning real analysis. Just make sure you see metric spaces in the table of contents. I wouldn't recommend Rudin PMA at the level you're targeting, and by the way, that Wikipedia page is too abstract and general for what you want. (IMO)

Comment: I mean--the page was perfect for me.

Comment: We had (in the Netherlands, at my university) a first year course "metrische topologie" (metric topology) which covered the definitions of metric space, lots of examples (for intuition building) and the general topology definitions of compactness, connectedness (using open sets, not metric notions) and finally completeness with as application Banach's fixed point theorem. In the second year we did "Inleiding topologie" (introduction to topology), which built on that, and Topologie 1,2 and 3 after that (if you did the right specialisation, as I did).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basics of metric spaces are typically covered in a first course in real analysis, which might be a course titled something like "Real Analysis", "Introduction to Real Analysis", "Introduction to Analysis", or occasionally "Advanced Calculus".  They would also be covered in a first course in general topology, which might be titled something like "Introduction to Topology".

To provide some distinction between these two courses, a real analysis course would focus on rigorously justifying and generalizing many ideas from calculus (with metric spaces being one important setting in which to generalize such ideas).  A topology course would focus on generalizing a certain special core of these ideas to a much more abstract and general setting called topological spaces (with metric spaces being a special case of topological spaces), possibly with some applications to some more geometric problems (the beginnings of algebraic topology).